# How to Read External HDD (Ubuntu) on OS X?

Tags: macos, unix, hdd

I do not want overwrite my OSX HDD, like the email-discussion [will ubuntu 16.04 support single boot on mac air?](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2016-March/284494.html) but use instead external HDD for Ubuntu Linux on mac air. 
I use USB3.0 to Sata cable with extra power supply 12V/2A.

1. Trying to read disk on OS X. 
   I get a warning that the disk is not readable by OS X. 
   I do not understand why. 
   I need to run Linux often, and I would like to run it from external 3.5" HDD.
2. Restart + option so boot manager successful boot. However, drivers are horrible. Network does not work over wlan, eth0 (usb tethering).

I can successfully read the disk in my cheapest Lenovo laptop in the market. (15", 250e, 2015 summer). My Macbook Air 2013-Mid, however, cannot do it, which is unbelievable. 
Challenges

1. Network drivers. For 14.04 or 16.04.
2. ...

### Comments

1. OSX thinks Ubuntu HDD is Windows at the boot manager. I think this is hilarious.

---

Why OS X cannot read HDD (Ubuntu)?

Comment: What format is it? If it's ExtFS, you'll need something like [Paragon ExtFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/)

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not know. It is default Windows disk where Ubuntu is installed. So probably NTFS or ExtFS.